# Why does Madara appear unhurt despite being covered in wounds?

Tags: naruto

I'm not sure if I have missed anything in the past, but Madara seems unphased by every attack.

Sasuke stabs a sword through his arm, but this isn't a problem.

All the tailed beasts stomp on Madara with their tails, and Madara doesn't even evade. Instead, he tanks the attack like it is no big deal.

What's going on here? Hashirama's senjutsu should only do so much, but it seems like Madara is simply invulnerable, aside from a little bleeding. Why isn't Madara getting hurt at all?

Is this what we call a plot shield?

Comment: Because I'm flippin' awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From chapter 659,

[image]

Madara mentions that due to the healing powers of Hashirama's he is able to recover must faster and is taking close to no damage.

So it is not just just Hashirama's senjutsu, but also his healing powers that have made Madara virtually invicible.

Also from the same chapter:

[image]

It is not that he is not being damaged, but that his healing is so fast that all damage seems to have no effect at all.

Comment: Here's what I don't get. Hashirama's healing powers come from his Senjutsu. But Madara also stated that Hashirama's Senjutsu was a disappointment to him, as he was expecting a great power. If Hashirama's senjutsu is a joke to Madara, it shouldn't be letting him live throughout all these brutal attacks. I guess the plot shield here, however, is his master of Senjutsu within seconds of stealing it. People like Minato couldn't even learn it and Senjutsu takes a long time to master.

Comment: I guess the second thing that is bothering me is that he tanked every single hit, and then healed everything afterwards. His healing wasn't immediately after each attack, but rather a one time massive healing in chapter 659. Just how was Madara able to sustain blow after blow in the chapters prior to 659?

Comment: @krikara Madara is a bigger legend than Minato. Even to Minato, the thought of Madara coming to life was dreadful. Also, could you please provide reference to the fact that Hashirama's healing powers come from his senjutsu. The other point that I would say is, the time between him tanking all the attacks and him healing is very minimal. It happens just after he takes the attack from the "tail whip"

Comment: He really only healed once, in chapter 659. We know this because his wounds faded upon the healing. From what I recall, there is no substantial evidence to prove that he healed inbetween attacks. As for the Senjutsu part, Madara only uses his heal after he drained the specific chakra from Hashirama. So the healing might not be dependent on senjutsu per se, but the (heightened) healing capabilities came when he absorbed the senjutsu chakra.

Answer (score 2):

As stated, it's not like he is taking no damage, but rather that the damage and the healing are going on side by side. Madara was only worried that he might have a hard time manipulating it. Still, even if the level of power may be a joke, healing is healing.

[image: worry]

Sasuke did manage to stab him in the arm but at that time Madara was blind - maybe he was not able to dodge in time, or maybe he was not worried about the injury. Besides, this also gave him time to talk to Sasuke and invite him to his side.

[image: blade]

As for the healing part, we only see Madara after the attack, not during it, and he also stated before that Hashirama didn't need hand signs to heal his injuries, and now that power belongs to him. He does not have to concentrate, he can just do it subconsciously. Besides, Madara does have Susano to protect him from physical attacks, so he doesn't have to form the big one. He can just form a small shield.

[image: power]

Comment: Okay, we know Madara heals himself in 659 because we can see it visually (steaming up and wounds closing). Now how do we know he is healing inbetween attacks such as Sasuke's sword or Gaara's sand? There are no visuals as far as I can tell.

Comment: @krikara Yes, there is no visual because of which we can't be sure of what happened, and we know already healing will take place. We see his healing only in 659, but we should also consider the level of attack he faced because of which it took him some time to heal completely. Even Madara complements those attacks, it should mean something coming from him.